# Debian не видит звуковую карту

Tags: linux, debian, alsa

Установил Debian 11 на ноутбук huawei matebook d15. Установка прошла успешно, запустился и все хорошо, но звука нету. В меню звука указано: "не найдено устройств ввода или вывода звука.". Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*cat /proc/asound/cards*

```
0 [Generic]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
             HD-Audio Generic at 0xd03c0000 irq 72
1 [acp]: acp - acp
         acp
```

Answer (score 0):

Новые звуковые карты на Intel 12ого поколения практически встроены в процессор. Отдельного кодека нет и нет отдельного устройства которое могло бы отпределиться в udev.

Чтоб запустить звук на этом ноутбуке нужно узнать адрес звуковухи и добавлять устройство вручную через /etc/modprobe.

Адрес можно узнать если скачаете официальный драйвер и там найдете скрипт установки. Да! в свежей Виндовс тоже звуковушку прописывают вручную)

Кроме этого нужно ещё загрузить правильную микропрограмму в него.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442371/how-do-i-add-firmware-to-get-es8336-audio-to-work

Попробуй с кастомным ядром, но сначала проверь та ли конфигурация.