# Почему пропал звук на ноутбуке и переустановка системы не помогает?

Tags: windows, windows-10, аудио, железо, ноутбук

На китайском ноутбуке марки "kuu" или "acobook", точного названия нет, пропал звук. Переустановил Windows 10, после чего пропал звук. Уже много раз переустановил систему, на диспетчере устройств стоит два неизвестных устройства, ни какие драйвера не подходят.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483026/debian-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83/1483549#1483549

Answer (score 0):

Новый звук на ноутах не определяется в системе никак. Нужно запросить у производителя скрипт установки. В случае с линукс ещё и драйвера "доработать напильником".